# passing token in soap header php

Tags: php, web-services, soap

Trying to make a call to the below web service, is this the correct way to pass a token in the soap header, its returning an incorrect token response, but the token is correct when i use it with soap ui..?

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient('http://api.fm- 
 web.co.za/webservices/AssetDataWebSvc/DriverProcessesWS.asmx?WSDL');

$token = array('Token'=>'XXXXXX');

$header = new SoapHeader('ass','soapenv',$token,false);

$response = $soapclient->__soapCall('GetDriverList',array(''),NULL,$header);

var_dump($response);
```

after some messing around this worked.

```
 $soapclient = new SoapClient('http://api.fm- 
  web.co.za/webservices/AssetDataWebSvc/DriverProcessesWS.asmx?WSDL');

//$token = array('Token'=>'XXXXXX');

 $header = new 

  SoapHeader('http://www.omnibridge.com/SDKWebServices/AssetData',
 'TokenHeader',array('Token'=>'XXXXXX'),false);

 //$DriverID = 3;
 $params = array('DriverID'=>'3');

 $response = $soapclient- 
 >__soapCall('GetDriver',array($params),NULL,$header);

 var_dump($response);
```

Comment: I am not an expert on soap authentication, but take a look at this example from the PHP doc on Soap authentication. Looks like the format is a bit different: http://php.net/manual/de/soapheader.soapheader.php#58245

Answer (score 0):

SoapHeader definition can be tricky especially if you're not familiar with SOAP.

My advise would be to use a WSDL to PHP generator that would provide you a SDK with the method to set any SoapHeader and particularly this SoapHeader.

You should try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project which should provide you the SoapHeader methods within the ServiceType\Get instance you'll have to create. Take a look to the generated `tutorial.php` file.